# Eclipse Indigo having problems installing m2e-wtp plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-wtp

I want to install in my eclipse Indigo the plugin m2e-wtp, that allow maven to build .war files.

I tried the using the market place and also the Install software option, but what I get is this:

[image]

In the website https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/ I see a message that says:

> Please note that, m2e-wtp and Sonatype's m2eclipse-wtp overlap and can
>   not be installed together.

But I don't understand if is this my case. I checked my installed plugins, and I don't see Sonatype mentioned anywhere, see this image of my m2e installed plugins:

[image]

I thought that maybe it was already installed so I tried to import a maven project that requires this plugin from an svn location and also from my local workspace, but it didn't work:

[image]

What is missing in my eclipse, why I cant projects that require the m2e-wtp plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not seeing the plugin in your installed plugins because installation failed:

> The m2eclipse-wtp project has moved to the Eclipse Foundation. *The m2eclipse-wtp plugin is now deprecated in favor of the newer m2e-wtp*
>
> **Automatic installation from the marketplace has been suspended**. m2eclipse-wtp 0.15.3 can be manually installed from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

From: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-wtp

You should install `m2e-wtp` through Eclipse Marketplace. Just be careful to actully install `m2e-wtp` and not `m2eclipse-wtp` (simply search for "m2e-wtp" as some searches actually bring up the old m2eclipse-wtp plugin). The m2e plugins have groupId of `org.eclipse.m2e`.

Comment: The marketplace drives me to the select features page where i can see that group id, but an error message pops and says  `Artifact not found: http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/content.jar.`
Is there a conflict? Maybe the wrong one is already installed, how can I check and fix?

Comment: Can't say, maybe a network glitch? You can see the installed plugins under `Help > About > Installation Details`. If m2eclipse-wtp is installed, it should be listed there.

Comment: No its not listed. There is nothing that looks like a network error to me. I am out of Ideas.
This is what the error log says:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/content.jar
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryStatusHelper.checkFileNotFound(RepositoryStatusHelper.java:297)
...`